# Publishing Infopath 2010 form to sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

This question is about publishing infopath 2010 form to sharepoint server 2010.I designed a form and publish it to a sharepoint library successfully.When I try to fill the form  and save it to sharepoint library,I am unable to  do it? Can Some one say How to save the filled infopath form to a library in share point 2010?

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: 'you are unable to do it'?---- And why would that be so? Share more details please.

Comment: Actually i filled the data by opening the form in infopath filler 2010 and then i click save.The it should be saved in sharepoint library directly.But it is asking me to save it  to local hard disk memory?BUt in Sharepoint 2007 and Infopath 2007 it is saved in the library itself.

Comment: Take a look at whathaveyoutried dot com and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

To really work "the Sharepoint way" you need to use some things:

A forms library with your Infopath form set up as the form template. The forms library is already configured correctly, but just to make sure you need to set the InfoPath form to open in the browser (via the Forms Services and the Infopath webpart respectively) - to open the file in the browser is a setting on the forms library. Your form should not open with the Infopath Form filler.

The easiest way to test this is to open Infopath 2010 and to create a form based on the "Sharepoint Form Library" which sets up everything correctly for you.

Comment: I have created it by using the sharepoint form library opetion in New menu in INfopath designer 2010.and published it to a form library.Then when i tried to add a new document to the library,it is opened in infopath filler?  it should be opened in browser but it is not doing so in my case? it is opened with ifnopath filler? So after publishing it to the library,shall i have to made any configuration for the library to open the form in browser? I checked the infopath service settings in centeral administartion?They are fine? So now what should I do?It will be great help if you provide links?

Comment: under Form Library Settings > Advanced Settings > Opening Documents in the Browser "Open in the browser" is checked instead of "Open in the client application". Also the "Document Template" should point to your form, so that when you create a new form your document template is used.

Comment: I checked in "Open in the browser"; in the "Document Template",I have the .xsn template and when I click "Edit Template";It is opening in Infopath Designer 2010; So Everything is fine;But still it is opening in Infopath filler instead of Opening in Browser. Any further suggestions? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In the save as dialog box of InfoPath filler, have you tried supplying:

```
http: <<SERVER_NAME>>/<<SITE>>..../<<FORM_LIBRARY NAME>>/<<FORM_NAME>>.xml
```

Comment: It is opening windows explorer save window.I tried yours?It says "not a valid path" ? Give suggestions further. Thank you

Comment: Yes dear, because InfoPath filler is a Windows Application, you will see a Windows 'Save As' dialog box. Now in that dialig box, type the full url of your Form Library and replace AllItems.aspx with a filename of your choice. The extension by default will be '.xml'.

Comment: You already stated it clearly in syntax form .I have done the same thing only.No use. Thank You

Comment: Well 'no use' doesn't help doseit? Did you get any error? Such  as:          The internat address is not valid; or Cannot find the URL '.....', please check your typing; or something else.

Comment: I typed everything correctly and still getting error.The error is "Not a valid path".